# After update: encrypted system boots to initramfs

Tags: boot, encryption, initramfs

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on an Acer ES1-311 laptop upgraded with an SSD, After the recent auto-update my system won't boot anymore, and sends me to initramfs after entering my encryption passphrase.

I had this problem before and used GRUB to just boot into the previous kernel, but obviously this can't be a permanent solution. Now, after the newest kernel update, I have the same problem. Here is what I see.

[image: Here is what i see]

Comment: What update are you talking about? The error/warning says that it can't find your root file system.

Comment: The automatic update funcion inside ubuntu. It happens after each kernel update i guess.

Comment: So how do i point GRUB to the root file system? Because when loading a previous kernel it works.